# What is the famous song about the independence of Bahia or Brazil?

Tags: quote-source, song-lyrics, portuguese-language, jorge-amado, home-is-the-sailor

Like many other novels by Jorge Amado, [*Home Is the Sailor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Is_the_Sailor_(novel)) is set in [Bahia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahia), one of the states of Brazil. On the second of July, one of the novel's characters organises a ceremony during which

> [trumpet sounds] wake the sun of the second of July, which—as **the famous song** claims—"on this day is Brazilian and shines brighter than on the first day of creation".

(I have no access to the Portuguese text or an English translation; the above quote is translated into English from the German translation by Curt Meyer-Clason, published by S. Fischer in 2013.)

The second of July is the day on which Bahia commemorates the end of the [Siege of Salvador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Salvador) in 1823, which occurred during the Brazilian War of Independence. (The [Independence of Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_of_Brazil) is actually celebrated on 7 September.)

I have not been able to determine which song is meant in the above quote. I could not find a reference to creation in the [Brazilian National Anthem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_National_Anthem), the [Brazilian Flag Anthem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Flag_Anthem), the [Hino da Independência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hino_da_Independ%C3%AAncia) or the [Brazilian Republic Anthem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Republic_Anthem). Apparently, the song is not one of these anthems. What is the famous song referenced in the quote?

Comment: ["Between Brazil and Bahia: Celebrating Dois de Julho in Nineteenth-Century Salvador"](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/arts/history/students/modules/hi2f1/programme/seminar4/kraay_celebrating_dois_de_julho.pdf) might have some useful info. [This page](https://www.salvadordabahia.com/en/the-2-of-july-independence-of-brazil-in-bahia/) claims that "Both in the books and in the interviews, as well as the curious and Bahia lovers, they told in their own way that the day raised without clouds and the sun reigned on July 2, 1823." which might be related?

Answer (score 4):

Probably "[Hino de Bahia](https://www.letras.mus.br/hinos-de-estados/1658611/)" as per [this Google Books reference](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bahia_s_Independence/nnqfDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=brazilian%20song%20bahia%20%22sun%20is%20brazilian%22&pg=PT69&printsec=frontcover):

> Dois de Julho patriots sang enthusiastically, as indicated by the many new anthems reported in the press. What is today known as the Dois de Julho anthem is usually attributed to Ladislau dos Santos Titara, whose poetry has often been cited on these pages (see figure 1.2). It begins with the lines:
>
> > The sun rises on Dois de Julho
> > It shines more brightly than on the first [of July]
> > It's a sign that on this day
> > Even the sun is Brazilian

The corresponding stanza in the Portuguese version is

> Nasce o Sol a 2 de Julho
> Brilha mais que no primeiro
> É sinal que neste dia
> Até o Sol, até o Sol é brasileiro

Found with a search for `brazilian song bahia "sun is brazilian"`

Comment: Admittedly, it still doesn't refer to the "first day of creation", but the line is "than on the first", and speaking of "the first day" without specifying a frame does suggest the *very* first day.

Comment: That seems to be the intended song. The first day "of creation" may be a mistranslation, but I have no access to the Portuguese text of the novel.